# Dynamics CRM + Azure Function Timeouts on bulk update

Tags: azure-functions, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an Azure function (Http triggered) which updates data in Dynamics CRM.

The data to be updated is beyond 100,000 so I have used the `ExecuteTransation` request and executing the requests in batches. However the Azure function times out after executing the first batch and it fails to process further records. What can I do to solve this?

Note: there is no webhook, since this is bulk update, I am directly calling the Azure function url to trigger it.

This is the code:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var cust = new Entity("account");
    cust.Id = list.Id;
    cust["code] = 1;
    cust["description"] = "Test";

    requestsCollection.Entities.Add(cust);

    if (multipleRequestWithResults.Requests.Count == 1000)
    {
        ExecuteBulkUpdate(multipleRequestWithResults);
        requestsCollection = new EntityCollection();
    }
}

public void ExecuteBulkUpdate(EntityCollection requestsCollection)
{
    var requests = new ExecuteTransactionRequest
        {
            Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection(),
            ReturnResponses = true
        };
}

foreach (var request in requestsCollection.Entities)
{ 
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest { Target = request };
    requests.Requests.Add(updateRequest);
}

try
{
    _serviceClient.Execute(requests);
}
catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Request failed for the {0} and the reason being: {1}",
                 ((ExecuteTransactionFault)(ex.Detail)).FaultedRequestIndex + 1, ex.Detail.Message);
    throw;
}

public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,"get","post", Route = "")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    // Call the bulk update from here
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```